# Slow UPDATE on SQL Server, even when no records are updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

No table locking issues confirmed.

I have the update statement similar to this.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.col1 = table2.col2 
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

This is taking forever even in the case whee there are no records to update

running the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

is instant.

SOLUTION FOUND: For what it's worth, I turned on the "Include Actual Execution Plan" as suggested and it recommended 3 indexes that I didn't have and now executes the entire stored procedure which is 190 SQL statements working on tables with 16 million rows in less than 1 minute.  Gracias to whoever suggested that.

Comment: It won't affected performance, but that `JOIN` syntax is the worst. Consider `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id` instead. It keeps `JOIN` logic separate from `WHERE` logic.

Comment: In SSMS, try the "include actual execution plan" option to check what SQL server is doing.

Comment: I like implict joins for INNER Joins, logically makes more sense to me and my research says that execution plans are identical for the different syntax. This problem is confirmed on on tons of databases running the same software even in single user mode. I shoudl probably note that table1 and table2 both contain about 16 million records each.

Comment: @Bart - and you realize you are updating 16 million tuples then right?  There is nothing in your query stating otherwise, the value of col1 is overwritten by col2, even if col1 and col2 contain the same value.  You should do something to the effect of `WHERE col2 <> col1` so that you are only updating values that are different.

Comment: @JonH, actually, I'm not that select statement returns nothing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by returns nothing.  If it returns nothing then you haven't done any updates.  List out your entire schema, the update statement you are using, expected results, etc.  We definately are trying to help you, but it appears some other processes is killing this?  Did you try using sql profiler to profile that specific database?  Is there any jobs that are continously running and performing a similiar update ?

Comment: @Bart -- What does your "instant" `SELECT` query actually return?  If it returns anything, then your `UPDATE` query is pulling the same set of records, and forcing the UPDATE regardless of whether the field values are the same or not.

Comment: First thing is a select statement is not the same as an update statement.  So comparing the two doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you are updating every row every time.  You need to add the following to your where clause:

```
AND table1.col1 <> table2.col2
```

You may need to add `ISNULL` wrappers to each side if these are nullable fields.

Which is faster: reading a book or writing over every word in the book the same exact word?  Just because you are writing the same value over the original value doesn't change the fact that you are writing values.

Now, if you had a where clause that filtered out records that had matching values and you still had really slow performance, then a likely culprit would be having too many indexes.  I'm guessing that's not your problem here...

Comment: +1 because col1 is updated (overwritten have you) by col2 for every row irregardless of anything.

Comment: ehh, didn't speed anything up, most of the time there will be no situation WHERE table1.id = table2.id but if there is I need the corrosponding columns to be equal. But the idea is good and will stay in the code.

Comment: I don't get why it would update every row every time, there is a `WHERE` clause, so it would only update the rows that have ids on table1 and table2. It could be zero or millions rows

Comment: Minor issue and you are correct, but this statement even as i originally posted it will almost never update anything anyway, but it's taking forever, like 2 hours to run.

Comment: @Bart - its probably some other process - can you use sql profiler?

Comment: In this example, while i erred in not relaying it better, table1.col1 and table2.col2 cannot be equal due to table2.col2 being a freshly initialized GUID with NEWID(), while your point is valid, it did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a proper join:

```
Update t
SET t.Col1 = t2.col2
FROM table1 t INNER JOIN
table2 t2 ON t.PK = t2.FK
```

After that check any additional processes running on that server.

Use `SQL Profiler` to see what is happening behind the scenes.  See if there are any unusual processes / jobs running that could affect the update.

> This is taking forever even in the case whee there are no records to
>   update

It's also as mentioned updating everything as long as the join exists, there is no where condition stopping it from not updating.  Every single row in the table is updated, the value that col1 had from table t is overwritten by the value of col2 from t2.

Also see the comments section:

> @Bart - and you realize you are updating 16 million tuples then right?
>   There is nothing in your query stating otherwise, the value of col1 is
>   overwritten by col2, even if col1 and col2 contain the same value. You
>   should do something to the effect of WHERE col2 <> col1 so that you
>   are only updating values that are different

Comment: +1 - It's probably going to be blocking of some sort.  I'm guessing the `UPDATE` wants locks even if it doesn't modify the data.

Comment: 99% of the time the OP statement and yours will have identical execution plans. Still...I'm with you on the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Yuck - the statement isn't about performance its about being more expressive, the ANSI join statement expresses that.

Comment: Not joining on PK and FK in your example t.PK will almost never have a match in t2.FK

Comment: @Bart - Just join on the columns that you require, mine was just an example of a one to many relationship, you probably have something different so use what you know - I'm definately not a mind reader so I don't know your schema.  Point is you are updating everything whether you like it or not.

Comment: @JonH How would I be updating everything if table1.id is never equal to table2.id?

Comment: @Bart - You have it wrong here, clearly you need to join to a set of ID's right?  The where clause is in there NOT for the ID's but to filter what data needs to be updated.  For instance lets say I have a table of Issues and Actions, There is a reference to an Issue by an IssueID, so I join on Issues.IssueID = Actions.IssueID but I `WHERE` on the field I am updating `WHERE Issues.Description <> Actions.Description`

Comment: table1.id and table2.id will almost never be equal and table1.col1 and table2.col1 WILL NEVER be equal so the excercise in putting AND table1.col1<>table2.col1 is largely academic because it is impossible for them to be equal since table2.col1 is a sql_variant column that has just been initialized witha  new guid via NEWID()

Comment: I dont get it - how are you joining these tables?  What kind of join are you looking for?  Post the exact table structures and you'll get a solid answer.  We are going by what you posted.

Comment: table1 (value SQL_VARIANT) table2 (value1 sql_variant, value2 sql_variant) if table2.value1 shows up in table1.value I want to change table1.value to table2.value2. Note that table2.value2 was just initialized with NEWID(). basically, I'm replacing an old guid with a new guid should it show up in table1.

Comment: UPDATE GuidTable SET new_guid = NEWID()
    -- SPEED ISSUE -- 
 UPDATE
  a
 SET 
  a.AttributeData_Value = b.new_guid
 FROM
  AttributeData a,
  GuidTable b
 WHERE
     a.AttributeData_Value = b.old_guid

Comment: So waht is the relationship between table1 and table2?

Comment: @Bart and that code is exactly where the issue is.  Again use the proper join syntax so you don't confuse the where as a join condition.  What are you joining to?  You are updating a.AttributeData_Value but you are also trying to join to it.  Please please clean your sql, I seriously cant help you if you don't clean it up and properly join the tables.  Sorry

Comment: Nothing really. GuidTable is just a temporary table that contains a list of GUIDS in the database and another column that has freshly created GUIDs so that if any of the new data coming in already has that GUID, I can change it and have a reference to the old and new GUID. AttributeData is the data that will be merged into another identical later in the proc, this step is just making sure the GUIDS don't already exist there so I don't get a PK violation when I attempt the insert. The GUIDs can already exist if the data originated in this database and is being brought back in.

Comment: UPDATE
  a
 SET 
  a.AttributeData_Value = b.new_guid
 FROM
  AttributeData a JOIN GuidTable b ON a.AttributeData_Value = b.old_guid
  GuidTable b

Answer (score 2):

```
Update t 
SET t.Col1 = t2.col2 
FROM table1 t 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.PK = t2.FK 
where t.Col1 <> t2.col2
```

This is what you should be running. SQL Server doesn't care that the values match it is updating them anyway.

And I'm with @JonH, those implict joins are a sql antipattern and were replaced by something better 20 yearsa ago, there is no excuse to still be writing queries that way. YOu get accidental cross joins and they are harder to maintain. Additonaly, in SQL Server the implicit left and right joins have been deprecated and they never worked correctly anyway. So if you have to change to a left join in maintenance, you then have to change the whole query because combining implict and explicit joins can get you wrong answers.

Comment: +1 - op should definitely use the proper `JOIN` syntax. But, I still don't understand why people is saying that the original `UPDATE` would update every row every time. If there is only on id on table1 that have a match on table2, then only 1 row will be updated, I guess that op is saying that

Comment: @Lamak what happens when `col1 == col2`? That update routine will still lock the record to perform the update even though you aren't updating anything, the values are the same so why bother.

Comment: @JonH - I understand that, and that's why I upvoted @HLGEM 's answer, but that definitely doesn't mean that the original query would update every row, there is a `WHERE` clause, and as the op stated, it will mostly match just a couple of rows or not rows at all

Comment: @Lamak - But even if it matches a single row, why would you update it if it really didn't need an update?  It makes no sense.

Comment: Most of the time, not at all, this query is just a safety net for when something happens to fall in both tables. 99.9% of the time, the update statement will do nothing, it's just taking an extrodinary amount of time to figure out it should be doing nothing. But the identical select statement instantly brings back no results.

Comment: It's withing about a 6K line stored procedure that merges data from two databases (via a DataSet.WriteXML() call) that is called via a .NET application using SQLAdapters.

Comment: There actually is no real where clause in the orignal SQL there isa join disguised as a where clause. This would update every record that is in both tables whether they already mathced or not.

Comment: It's called an implicit join and apparently is the source of much hatred around here. Never really met a programmer that took offense to them. Sorta like conditionals, I guess, depends on what you want to get all wound up about.

Comment: It is an implicit jopin and it is a very poor technique. It causes errors that you will not get with explicit joins and it makes maintenance harder and it is makes the query less clear. There is no advantage to using them and several disadvantages.